# Selecting column sum between date range is selecting old dates

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm having issues with selecting a range of rows between specific dates and getting the sum of a specific column.

Here is the function I'm using for the User model:

```
public function monthlyStats($date)
{
    $start = date('n/1/y',strtotime($date)); // first day of the month
    $end = date('n/t/y',strtotime($date)); // last day of the month

    return UserStats::where('uid','=',"'$this->uid'")->whereBetween('date', array("'$start'", "'$end'"))->sum('duration');
}
```

So basically, it is selecting the user stats where user id = X and the stats date is between x and x date...it then takes the sum of the duration column between the dates.

Here is what the actual query looks like:

```
select sum(`duration`) as aggregate from `user_stats` where `uid` = '123456' and `date` between '8/1/14' and '8/31/14'
```

The issue I'm having is that it is selecting extremely old dates...for example, it's selecting rows that are from 8/1/08, rather than from the current year `14`

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the data type for date?

Comment: try printing out the $start and $end.. make sure its in the correct format, aka 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'

Comment: varchar(10)...I'm working from an old database from a previous webmaster...

Comment: @JohnRuddell Yupp, it's printing the correct date formats.

Comment: thats your problem convert the varchar to a date field... so like in mysql you would do STR_TO_DATE(). convert it to a date and the comparison will work